# boolean algebra - theorems

Tags: boolean, algebra, theorem

I have a homework question "Show the following is true using theorems.  State which theorem you use at each step." This is just one of many problems I have! So, if you can help me with this one problem than I can apply what I learn to finish the rest. I don't want a handout; I just don't know where to start or what to do. I have looked through the different theorems in the book and I don't see how any would apply to this!

```
A'BD' + BCD + ABC' + AB'D = A'BD' + BCD + ABC' + AB'D BC'D' + A'BC + ABD
```

Should I group two or more and work from there? Since, we are only working with '+'
then I  should only need these types of theorems?

I have a book that shows the different theorems. But it still doesn't help me tackle this problem. Are we to prove how the first part equals the second part? To me that's expanding and not reducing.

Comment: This isn't quite programming related. Perhaps try http://math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: You've got a bug, I think, in the expression - there should be some operator between the "`AB'D`" and "`BC'D'`" on the RHS of the equation.  Either that or you've got a trivially false term because "`B'B`" and "`DD'`" are both trivially false.

Comment: I dislike the requirement to "Use theorems." Thats like saying, "Use math." What can you use besides theorems and axioms?

Comment: Shouldn't there be something between `AB'D` and `BC'D'`?

Comment: Indeed, after attempting to give you some help, the four terms on the LHS of the '=' are repeated on the RHS, so we need to know what is supposed to go between the "`AB'D`" and "`BC'D`" terms before anything useful can be done.

Comment: Assuming + is logical OR, what is the apostrophe?

Comment: The apostrophe is negation. So `A'` is the same as `Ā`

Answer (score 0):

In that big mess you could probably factor things out, apply theorems such as Demorgan's theorem, rearrange, and find that certain things cancel out or simplify, such as A(B+B') or BB'. That's just the general idea, not saying any of this will occur in that particular problem. It's just like normal algebra. Don't be intimidated by the fact that you are using letters, compliments, etc.